# Codeigniter combining query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to union these 2 queries but I am getting error

> Call to a member function num_rows() on array error

I am unsure of what I have done wrong. I hope someone can see if I have done the query correctly.

I have these tables:

- Adults
- Children
- Transactions
- PersonTransactions

The PersonTransactions table links up the other 3 tables via the ids
The Adults and Children table share similar fields but not entirely thats why I separated them.

Query Code Below:

```
$this->db->limit($limit,$start);
$this->db->select('cn.firstname AS Firstname, cn.lastname AS Lastname,t.id AS id,pt.personType AS PersonType,p.name AS ProductName,t.adults AS Adults,t.children AS Children,t.total AS Total,t.country as Country,t.transactionDate as TransactionDate');  
$this->db->from('PersonTransactions AS pt'); 
$this->db->join('Products as p','pt.productID = p.id','LEFT');
$this->db->join('Transactions as t','pt.transactionID = t.id AND pt.personType="child"','LEFT');
$this->db->join('Children as cn','cn.id = pt.personID AND cn.personType=pt.personType','LEFT');
$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('pn.firstname AS Firstname, pn.lastname AS Lastname,t.id AS id,pt.personType AS PersonType,p.name AS ProductName,t.adults AS Adults,t.children AS Children,t.total AS Total,t.country as Country,t.transactionDate as TransactionDate');
$this->db->from('PersonTransactions AS pt'); 
$this->db->join('Products as p','pt.productID = p.id','LEFT');
$this->db->join('Transactions as t','pt.transactionID = t.id AND pt.personType="adult"','LEFT');
$this->db->join('Person as pn','pn.id = pt.personID AND pt.personType=pt.personType','LEFT');
$query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
$query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION".$query2);
```

Comment: try using `$query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);
`

Comment: Please show more code where you using num_rows....... else try this
$query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION".$query2);
return $query->result_array();

Comment: Sorry everyone! Thank you for your help. I found out that my database was poorly made and so I have remade it.